# Filter on static content outside tomcat webapp directory

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

Im using tomcat 7.0 and in my server.xml I have this:

```
<Context docBase="C:/xampp/tomcat/temp" path="/testapp/files" />
```

to allow the user to download files that are placed in the /temp directory. However, I would also like to limit some users from downloading files depending on their user-role. I describe my filter in webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml like this:

```
  <filter>
  <filter-name>DownloadFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>Main.downloadFilter</filter-class>   
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>DownloadFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/files</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

The filter is clearly available for use, as I get no errors when I start the server, however, it is not applied upon downloading a file as I've placed a System.out.println statement inside the filter, and this statement is never invoked.

Here is the filter doFilter() code

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;             
     System.out.println(req.getRemoteUser());


    if (req.isUserInRole("freeuser")==true){
        //check in DB if downloaded 2 today. CLEAR PAST DAYS. IF NOT DOWNLOADED - FILTER, ELSE NOT.
          String user = req.getRemoteUser(); 
        Database db = new Database();
        if (db.checkDownloadLimit(user)==false){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Anyone? Or is this not possible?

Comment: I would say that rather than adding an external folder to the docbase, you should have just made a servlet that reads the file from there and writes it out byte by byte only for authorized users.

Comment: Thanks! Will do that